# ProgressBar decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a cycle. the number of iterations depends on the choice of the user. I get the number of double, but the progress bar only accepts int;

```
double progr = 100 / (listBox2.Items.Count * listBox4.Items.Count);
progressBar1.Value += progr; <-
```

Comment: I count at least 3 issues on these 2 lines.

Comment: Did you try yo cast it?

Comment: move the decimal point, and hope that both your list boxes never have 0 elements Edit: just found what I believe to be leppies third issue ^.^

Comment: if you don't understand the question, why is laughing?

Comment: @Sayse: Actually, I count another two ;p So 5 issues in 2 lines.

Comment: @KonstantinMokhov - You know that the value will only take an int, and to avoid losing precision you should convert the decimal part of the number to a whole number. leppie - `1.` 100 should be 1 `2.` Counts can equal 0 `3.` <- invalid syntax `4.` progr creates an int and cant find the fifth yet

Comment: @Sayse: I thought I would just spell it out as answer to point the OP in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to use a progressbar to show the processing of TotalCount_n items, you would typically use this statements:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = TotalCount_n;
progressBar1.Value = currentItem;
```

if you have two processes, like TotalCount_n and TotalCount_m, you can write

```
progressBar1.Maximum = TotalCount_n * TotalCount_m;
progressBar1.Value = currentItem_n * TotalCount_m + currentItem_m;
```

if you want to calculate a percentage with an int, you can write:

```
int percentage = (currentItem * 100) / TotalCount_n;
```

if you have a processbar showing percentages, then you use

```
//progressBar1.Maximum = 100; // set in the designer
progressBar1.Value = (currentItem * 100) / TotalCount_n;
```

if you have a processbar with a random maximum, you can also write:

```
progressBar1.Value = (currentItem * progressBar1.Maximum) / TotalCount_n;
```

but then you need to take care, that the numbers wont get too high. so if TotalCount_n and the maximum is both higher than 65000, you will get an overflow because the product currentItem * progressBar1.Maximum might get over 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

```
double progr = 100 / (listBox2.Items.Count * listBox4.Items.Count);
progressBar1.Value += progr;
```

Issues detected in those 2 lines:

1. Possible division by zero
2. Integer division and assignment to `double`
3. Assignment of `double` to integer property
4. Use of increment instead of assignment to `Value`
5. Incorrect division to determine progress (operands are swapped)