# How to change the value of a progress bar to a double?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, typeconverter

I am attempting to have a sound play at specific increments of a progress bar's progress. The progress bar has a max of 80 and is controlled by a timer that has an interval of 100 (thus total duration of 8 seconds). In the first case the sound plays because 80/16 = 5 which is an integer, but nothing else plays. How can I convert the progressbar value to a double? Or is that even the right track? Thank you!

```
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (1/16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (2 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (3 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (4 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (5 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (6 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (7 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (8 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (9 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (10 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (11 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (12 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (13 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (14 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (15 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
            if (checkBox1.Checked && progressBar1.Value == (progressBar1.Maximum * (16 / 16)))
                hiphopkick.Play();
```

Comment: You need to learn about numbers. All your fractions are 0 because you don't understand integer division. And testing floats for equality will be the next cause of error..

Comment: Standard C# trap, you are using integer division so you'll always get 0.  Use 1.0 / 16 instead.  Removing the parentheses would work too.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you about how it works. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23822781/4323328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use decimal, not double.

[**Binary floating point and .NET**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)

Second when you divide two ints the result is int. So `12/16 = 0`. To make it work correctly you should write it like this:

```
var decimalRes = progressBar1.Maximum * (13 / (decimal)16);
```

Comment: In this case, `decimal` doesn't provide any extra precision over `double`.  `13.0 / 16.0` has an exact representation as a `double`.